# Toggle bootstrap modal after Ajax contact load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I’m using bootstrap toggle to load a modal with remote content

```
<button data-toggle="modal" href="content.php?id=<?php echo strip_tags($results['id']);?>" data-target="#myModal">Click me</button>
```

But when load this content is loaded Ajax modal toggle will stop working. Is there any workaround for this? Appreciate your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap modals have a method for doing this.

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
```

That should do the work. Or you can use

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dummy button for invoking ajax call and in response you can trigger click event for the actual Modal link.

Adding my example below:

```
<button id="beforeModalLoad">Show MOdal</button>

<button data-toggle="modal" id="actualLinkToModal" style="display:none;"   data-target="#myModal">Click me</button>

$("#beforeModalLoad").click(function(){
    $.ajax(function(){
     ....
     success: function(data){
      $("#actualLinkToModal").trigger( "click" );
     }
  })
})
```

Please acknowledge if it helps.